# Does a grouped RadListView support headers/footers?

Tags: android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, telerik

I can't find any examples of this and wonder if it's even possible? I know about the group header/group footer, but is it possible to have a single header/footer for an entire ListView that has grouping enabled?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [answer](https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-implement-listview-headertemplate#7e8KTGvqwUWj2TQcl1L_eQ) from the Telerk forums:

> Only the Android RadListView control supports header and footer. You can check [this](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/android/controls/listview/listview-other#header-and-footer) article to see how to set them. The iOS TKListView control does not support header/footer, which means that even with custom renderer this scenario cannot be supported.

**For Android, you can achieve that via Custom Renderer, there's the related code snippet in the [answer](https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-implement-listview-headertemplate#7e8KTGvqwUWj2TQcl1L_eQ). But for iOS, it seems it's not supported.**

And it provide a workaround, which may help you:

> The only workaround that comes to my mind for iOS (and for Android with no custom renderer) is to group the items in the list view in a single group and use the group header. [Here](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/controls/listview/features/listview-features-grouping) you can find more information about grouping.

Comment: I'm only targeting Android, however, I'm using xamarin.forms, do you know of a XAML example?